# Using thread to insert data into SQLite

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, insert

I am using ADO.Net method in my SQLite for commit (insert, delete, update) functions and my save processes are running in a multiple threading way.

Is there a method that can prevent the error that occurs when my thread is trying to make off with some function while another function has not completed its run?

I'm using `thread.speed(xxx)` to test my program.

Or how can I check the data already exists before the insert attempts to do the work?

Answer (score 0):

Try at the event level using transaction Scope. Might be it help you.

Usage:

```
using System.Transactions;
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //Your various methods 
    scope.complete();
}
```